# reading Azure application insights report

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an API call that sometimes takes like 10 seconds to run.

[image]

I've checked the duration for each external call and it seems fine. I mean that there is external resource calls so I would understand that it should wait for ~200 ms.

What I don't understand is the time between a resource call and then there is nothing in between for **6 seconds** until the next step. 
What could be the reason?

Furthermore, it usually takes less than 1 second so I don't think my could cause a wait of 6 seconds :|

Comment: It seems that there is a lot going on in this api method. Maybe there is a delay in the code between those dependency calls. How does you complete action code looks like? Because from just this graph we cannot explain why it sometimes can take that long.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is the time between a resource call and then there is nothing in between for 6 seconds until the next step. What could be the reason?

If we call multiple dependencies for the first time, there is really a big gap in different dependencies normally. We need a period of time to load the new dependency. After the first call, if we run the same page again, we could see there is only slightly  delay time in different dependencies. And later call results  are similar to this.

If your problem does not happen on calling dependencies the first time,  you could find which dependency’s duration is longest by clicking ‘View as timeline’. And you could optimize the code about this dependency in your project. Sometimes the delay also occurred in our internal processing.  The official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies)  also have related explanation.

> **Request timeline**
>
> In a different case, there is no dependency call that is particularly long. But by switching to the timeline view, we can see where the delay occurred in our internal processing:

Call dependencies the first time:

[image]

Call after the first time:

[image]